# GWT-Textcell not firing the onclick event

Tags: java, gwt, enums

I am trying to capture the onclick event from a textcell. why does not this fire the click event -

```
        TextCell tempCell = new TextCell() {
            @Override
            public void onBrowserEvent(Cell.Context context, Element parent, String value, 
                    NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
                 if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
                     Window.alert("Clicked me from cell");
                 }
            }
        };
        Column<Contact, String> tempColumn = new Column<Contact, String>(tempCell) {
          @Override
          public String getValue(Contact object) {
            return object.address;
          }


        };
        table.addColumn(tempColumn, "Address");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work because TextCell does not consume any events. You must sub-class AbstractSafeHtmlCell instead and tell it which events you want to consume by passing them into the constructor.

This will do:

```
private class MyTextCell  extends AbstractSafeHtmlCell<String> {

 /**
  * Constructs a TextCell that uses a {@link SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer} to render
  * its text.
  */
  public MyTextCell() {
    super(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance(), "click");

  }



  @Override
  public void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
      sb.append(value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent,
        String value, NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    GWT.log("Click event!!!!!! Not listening to anything else");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe GWT events are enums, for example, Event.ONCLICK.

So to solve, try to directly use the Event.ONCLICK.toString() and see if the event fires.

In general, rememeber its important not to have loose strings in your code because assuming that the name of the event is "click" is a very fragile technique which could render your application disfunctional if anything changes .